# JiBx Maven build issues

Tags: build, maven, compilation, jibx

I have a pom.xml which I use to generate sources from schema and bind and compile.

```
<!--  <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jibx-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
            <directory>src/main/resources/schema</directory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
            <execution>
            <goals>
            <goal>schema-codegen</goal>
            </goals>
            </execution>
            </executions>
            </plugin> -->
             <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jibx-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <targetDirectory></targetDirectory>
                <directory>src/main/resources/jibx</directory>
                <includes>
                    <includes>*binding.xml</includes>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>template-binding.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <verbose>false</verbose>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bind</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-binding</id>
                </execution>

            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

So When I try to generate the .java and binding.xml, I uncomment the first part of the  and comment the bottom. This generates the .java and binding.xml.
Now, I copy the binding.xml to `src/main/resources/jibx` and java class to `com.models.response package`. Then I run the bind and compile-binding target by uncommenting those lines and commenting top  part. I could see `JiBX_bindingFactory.class` and 'JiBX_bindingResponse_access.class' in 'target.com.models.response' package.

Problem is when I run a test class and try to unmarshall the response inputstream into "Response.class", I am getting `Exception in thread "main" org.jibx.runtime.JiBXException: JiBx Exception: Unable to access binding information for class com.models.response.Response
Make sure the binding has been compiled`
error.

Please note: I do all this in Eclipse and default Output folder shows '/build'. I tried copy-pasting of Jibx classes into 'build' folder as well. Still facing same issue.

Please help!!!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

Commenting and uncommenting pom sections is not an ideal way to do development.  It looks like you have not bound these goals to relevant maven life cycle phases. e.g. `schema-codegen` to `process-resources`

As the maven jibx plugin [documentation](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/maven-jibx-plugin/) specifies, you would need to run the following goals as appropriate for tests.

```
jibx:test-bind Runs the JiBX binding compiler on the test classes.
jibx:test-schema-codegen Generates Java test sources from XSD schemas.
```

Comment: It is fixed now. In Eclipse I was having same folder as output classes as that of POM.xml output folder and Build Automatically ON. So everytime JibX binding classes are generated, eclipse replaces it with just java-class files.

Comment: @narayanan What was the fix for this? Did you just end up changing the target directory for the JIBX binding output?